# How to output a map color name in sass?

Tags: sass

I have a map using the following structure:

```
$palette: (

  scarlet: (
    base: $scarlet,
    light: lighten($scarlet, $tone-level),
    dark: darken($scarlet, $tone-level),
    trans: transparentize($scarlet, $trans-level)
  ),

  emerald: (
    base: $emerald,
    light: lighten($emerald, $tone-level),
    dark: darken($emerald, $tone-level),
    trans: transparentize($emerald, $trans-level)
  ),
)


 @each $color-key, $color-variants in $unicorn-palette {
    $base-color-value: map-get($color-variants, 'base');

$light: map-get($color-variants, 'light');
$dark: map-get($color-variants, 'light');
$trans: map-get($color-variants, 'trans');
```

I want to be able to access my colour values through the following logic and printing their key name as well as hex value before and after:

```
&.#{$color-key} {
      background-color: $base-color-value;

      &:before { content: "#{$color-key}"; }
      &:after { content: "#{$base-color-value}"; }

      &--light {
      background-color: $light;
        &:before { content: "#{$color-key}"}
        &:after { content: "#{$light}"; }
      }

      &--dark {
      background-color: $dark;
      &:after { content: "#{$dark}"; }
      }

      &--trans {
      background-color: $trans;
      }


     }  
  }
}
```

So the styles would look as follows `emerald--light` which is working. However I can access the hex and colour value of "base" but not the variations which I want to print inside my container alongside the hex value for this colour. This is what I have been trying, but $colour-key only picks up the first base colour and not the "light" tint in the map. It only prints the correct light hex value with the wrong colour name.

```
      background-color: $light;
        &:before { content: "#{$color-key}"}
        &:after { content: "#{$light}"; }
      }
```

How can I get the `emerald-light` to display the hex and `emerald-light` corresponding name next to it?

Comment: Could you reproduce this in JSFiddle? I'm trying to follow in my head but it's  pretty convoluted.

Comment: Hi Jack. I only have a pen: http://codepen.io/Itagiba/pen/BzjGrj does this help?

Comment: Same thing :) I'll get back to you

Comment: Thanks, basically I am totally perplexed at how difficult it seems to extract the map "light, dark, trans etc." into a function instead of their values.